# Which audio playback options exist for playing MP3 or AAC files on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-audio, avaudioplayer

I figured out AVAudioPlayer can play MP3 or AAC. But it also has a big latency. It seems to be loading the entire file into memory first.

Are there other, more efficient options than AVAudioPlayer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are [`AVPlayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [`MPMoviePlayerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (which, despite its name, can also play audio files). `MPMoviePlayerController` tends to be a bit easier to use in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenAL library for that which is very very efficient for the purpose you are talking about

Here is the link

https://github.com/kstenerud/ObjectAL-for-iPhone

Have a look .Its too easy to integrate and implement.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

The lowest-level and lowest-latency option that you can get on iOS is RemoteIO.

This question has some more relevant information: [Playback MP3 using RemoteIO and AudioUnits on iPhone... possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857637/playback-mp3-using-remoteio-and-audiounits-on-iphone-possible)